# Set requirements for custom bundle

Tags: symfony, bundle, composer-php, vendors

I try to set requires for my custom bundle. It located in <kbd>src\CpmName\NameOfBundle</kbd>. I want that when I run `php composer update` for this bundle will installed Guzzle (my bundle is client for some public API).
I put file <kbd>composer.json</kbd> to <kbd>src\CpmName\NameOfBundle</kbd> but it doesn't work.

Comment: composer only knows the bundles it installed in `vendor`, it won't read your `composer.json` file in the bundle. Why not add guzzle to your `composer.json` at the root of the app?

Comment: This bundle will be used in others my projects and I want to make process installtion bundle more automatic.
So, I try to pack my bundle to vendor and upload it to packagist.org

Comment: Add you bundle in the `require` part of `composer.json` of you Symfony2 directory, then update the vendors, it should install your bundle and its dependencies if you added Guzzle in the `composer.json` file of your bundle.